# Intellisense not showing the using keyword

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I see a strange issue today.

When using a class (either custom or .net), on pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> keys, the intellisense would suggest to add the global "using" namespace.

But it's not showing it now. It only shows the path of that class.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you only meet this issue for this class and it is a custom or system class? Please have a try with a .net system class and check this potential fixes(Ctrl+.) works fine or not? If only this class have this issue, please share more detail information about it, I will try to reproduce it on my side, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor-> C# ->General` and Tick `Auto list members` and `Parameter Information`:

[image]

**Or** Tick `Show completion list after a character is typed` under `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor-> C# -> IntelliSense`.